# Сортировка массива по двум ключам

Tags: c#, массивы

Как отсортировать элементы массива по двум ключам? Элементом массива является запись, два поля которой – два ключа.

Comment: Покурите вот этот пример: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: при использовании устойчивых сортировок, можно просто выполнить последовательно две сортировки в обратном порядке. Т.е. сначала сортируем по второму ключу, потом по первому, в результате вторые ключи будут разделены на сортированные группы с одинаковым первым ключом. Почитайте об устойчивости сортировок хотя бы на вики, и поймете о чем я.

Comment: То, что это нужно не вам, а вашему преподавателю, никому не интересно, и только злит всех, потому что показывает, что вы просто хотите спихнуть на нас домашку. Отредактировал вопрос, убрал нерелевантную часть.

Answer (score 9):

> Элементом массива является запись, два поля которой – два ключа

Давайте для начала создадим такую запись:

```
class Record
{
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
}
```

Для примера я создаю и заполняю массив значениями случайных чисел

```
var random = new Random();

var records = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(n => new Record
{
    Key1 = random.Next(100).ToString(),
    Key2 = random.Next(100).ToString()
}).ToArray();

foreach (var record in records)
    Console.WriteLine(record.Key1 + " " + record.Key2);
Console.WriteLine();
```

Для сортировки используем LINQ:

```
records = records.OrderBy(r => r.Key1).ThenBy(r => r.Key2).ToArray();

foreach (var record in records)
    Console.WriteLine(record.Key1 + " " + record.Key2);
Console.WriteLine();
```

Метод `OrderBy` сортирует по первому ключу, затем метод `ThenBy` дополнительно сортирует последовательность по второму ключу, сохраняя порядок первой сортировки.

В синтаксисе запросов сортировку можно записать так:

```
records = (from r in records
           orderby r.Key1, r.Key2
           select r)
           .ToArray();
```

В данном случае просто указываем ключи, по которым осуществляется сортировка, в нужном порядке через запятую.

---

Применим этот способ для сортировки списка файлов по имени и расширению:

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(".").EnumerateFiles();

var sortedFiles = files
    .OrderBy(file => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name))
    .ThenBy(file => file.Extension);
```

Comment: Примером сортировки по двум ключам может служить список файлов, имеющих одинаковые имена и разные расширения. Список упорядочен по именам, а для каждого имени – по расширениям.
К

Comment: @Denis - добавил пример с файлами.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали, по каким ключам идёт сортировка, а также порядок сортировки. Будем считать, что ключи - это целые числа, а сортировка ведется по возрастанию значений этих чисел, причём при сортировке сначала учитывается значение первого ключа, а затем второго (т.е. [2, 4] будет стоять перед [2, 5], но после [1, 10]). Тогда код будет примерно следующим:

```
    for (i = 0; i < c1.GetLength(0); i++)
       for (j = 0; j < c1.GetLength(1); j++)
       {
          /* Проходим по неотсортированным элементам массива
             (такие элементы будут расположены справа и ниже
              текущей позиции i, j */

          for (k = i; k < c1.GetLength(0); k++)
             for (l = j + 1; l < c1.GetLength(1); l++)
             {
                /* Если первый ключ (FirstValue) у найденного
                   элемента меньше первого ключа элемента, с которым
                   идёт сравнение, либо первые ключи совпадают, а второй
                   ключ (SecondValue) у найденного элемента меньше,
                   то эти элементы нужно поменять местами */

                if (c1[i, j].FirstValue > c1[k, l].FirstValue ||
                   (c1[i, j].FirstValue == c1[k, l].FirstValue &&
                    c1[i, j].SecondValue > c1[k, l].SecondValue))
                {
                   /* Обмен значений FirstValue и SecondValue между ячейками
                      [i, j] и [k, l] массива c1 через вспомогательную
                      переменную того же типа, что и ваша структура - 
                      реализуйте самостоятельно */
                }
             } 
       }
```

Этот код не является оптимальным: есть другие, более совершенные варианты сортировок. Но для понимания того, что необходимо сделать, он подойдет. И пожалуйста, формулируйте задачу более четко в следующий раз - как я и сказал, не совсем понятно, какие ключи и как вам нужно сортировать. Удачи!

Comment: Примером сортировки по двум ключам может служить список файлов, имеющих одинаковые имена и разные расширения. Список упорядочен по именам, а для каждого имени – по расширениям.